# What is the conjugate of the relator in group representation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, algorithms, combinatorial-group-theory

I need to know this to understand the definition of isoperimetric function.

But is for $abc$ it the $a^{-1}b^{-1}c^{-1}$ or $c^{-1}b^{-1}a^{-1}$ or $cba$? (I think that the first)

P. S. It is not trivial to google this.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are asking, but neither $a^{-1}b^{-1}c^{-1}$ nor $c^{-1}b^{-1}a^{-1}$ is a conjugate of $abc$ in the free group on $a,b,c$. But $c^{-1}b^{-1}a^{-1}$ is the inverse of $abc$.

Comment: Maybe you mean to ask: which is a *consequence* of $abc$, where by "consequence" I mean is the product of conjugates of the word and their inverses?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/0810.4060.pdf

Comment: I think here in 11 page R- is mean same.

Comment: @DerekHolt  ////////

Comment: So I think if I would paint each new cycle in standart construction of Van Campen diagram in new color the count of colours wich have bound is that I need for isoperimetric function.